# CSS- Password field height in Mobile Safari and Chrome

Tags: css, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

I am having an issue with the height of the password field differing from that of the textfield above it even if I apply style="height:22px" directly to both elements.

Current HTML:

```
  <h2>Username 
    <label>
      <input name="email" type="text" id="email" style="height:22px" />
      </label>
  </h2>
  <h2>Password  
    <label>
      <input name="password" type="password" id="password"style="height:22px"  />
      </label>
  </h2>
```

Current CSS:

```
#logonForm input[type=text], #logonForm input[type=password] { 
    font-size:18px;
    border-radius:8px;
    padding-left:10px;
    height:22px;
    width:364px;
}
```

This renders (with or without the style attribute) as

[image: screenshot]

How do I make it render as the same height and why is this occurring?

Comment: You need a space between attributes: `id="password" style="height:22px"`

Comment: @Steve - added; no change

Comment: @Adrift Added to style sheet; refresh has not shown a change but no idea how to force hard refresh on mobile borwser.

Comment: Have you tried adding an explicit `line-height` to your CSS?

Comment: OK so current style is `#logonForm input[type=text], #logonForm input[type=password] { 
 font-size:18px;
 border-radius:8px;
 padding-left:10px;
 height:initial;
 line-height:22px;
 width:364px;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
}`  cleared Safari cache but no change in display; also removed style attribute from html

Comment: Can you provide a link?  Also, why do you only set `padding-left` and not all `padding`.  Try: `padding: 0 0 0 10px;`

Comment: Maybe this will prove illuminating?  http://pockyway.com/logon.php

Comment: Steve- that looks like it was the issue.  Adding specific padding makes Safari do right.  Can't seem to find a way to clear Chrome cache but I'm a happy camper.  Want to add your solution as answer?

Comment: Found cache in Chrome under Privacy... Clearing shows corrected sizes.  Yay!

Comment: Glad it worked.  Just added it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to add explicit padding for ALL sides, not just padding-left:

```
#logonForm input[type=text], #logonForm input[type=password] { 
    font-size:18px;
    border-radius:8px;
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
    height:22px;
    width:364px;
}
```